# Absolutely continuous and Lipschtiz $f$ has derivative in $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be absolutely continuous and Lipschitz on $[0,1]$. I would like to show that $f'\in L^\infty([0,1])$.

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous, then it is differentiable almost everywhere on $(0,1)$ and
$$\int_x^y f'=f(y)-f(x)$$
for every $0\le x<y\le 1$. Furthemore, since $f$ is Lipschitz, then the quantity
$$\sup_{x,y\in[0,1]}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=\sup_{x,y\in[0,1]} \frac{1}{|x-y|} \left|\int_x^y f'\right| =: M$$
is finite. But by Lebesgue's differentiation theorem,
$$\lim_{y\to x} \frac{1}{|x-y|} \int_x^y f' \to f'(x).$$
Thus,
$$|f'(x)|\le M$$
almost everywhere, implying that $f'\in L^\infty([0,1])$.

Is this proof correct, and are there other proofs of the same result?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. I think there is room to simplify just using the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$ means $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| \leq M \implies |f'(x)| \leq M \quad \text{a.e.},$$ hence $$\|f'\|_{\infty} \leq M$$ by definition of esssup.

Comment: I think you can skip the condition "absolutely continuous" since "Lipschitz on $[0,1]$" implies "absolutely continuous".